# How to display the ContactItems Firstname in a ListBox

Tags: list, outlook, listbox, outlook-addin, contactitem

I got a list of Outlook Contacts and want to display them in a ListBox. This is the code I use to add every Contact to the ListBox but

```
foreach (ContactItem contact in contactItemsList)
            {
                ListBox_contacts.Items.Add(contact);
            }
```

The problem I have is with the output of the ListBox. Rather than showing the FirstName of each Contact it shows only: System.__ComObject

I read some things with overriding the ToString()- method but wasn´t able to understand how I should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just

```
ListBox_contacts.Items.Add(contact.Firstname);
```

Comment: After adding every item to the list I just had to change the DisplayMember of the list like this: `ListBox_contacts.DisplayMember = "FirstName";`. Now it displays the FirstNames of each item in the ListBox like I wanted to